# Excel Lookup function to isolate duplicate data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I am currently working on a school project alongside a major company to help streamline their shipping process.

We were given two large Excel docs and had to isolate matching shipment numbers from each of the two sheets.

Can I perform a look up function in order to do this?  Or is there perhaps a better formula to suit these purposes?

Comment: `MATCH` is a good place to start

Comment: `COUNTIF(range,criteria)` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX/MATCH to find every ID where there is at least one match.

```
INDEX(PullThisData,MATCH(MatchingThisCell,FromThisColumn),0))
```

To find the number of matches:

If you copy the following formula along each row of data, you can then see how many matches you get on one sheet to the other per shipment ID

```
IF(COUNTIF(Range,Cell)>1,"",Cell)
```